# ¿Cómo hacer que un programa Java cree números aleatorios en un JDialog?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un sistema/juego en `NetBeans` sobre bingo, pero no se como hacer para que se crean números aleatorios para cada tarjetón de cada jugador de este juego.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Añado una pregunta: ya intentaste _algo_ para generar los números aleatorios? buscaste algo? **Edita tu pregunta** y añade toda la información relevante.

Comment: Necesitas un generador de números aleatorios que te devuelva números aleatorios entre dos límites. Para evitar repetir números tendrás que ingeniártelas de alguna manera para llevar la cuenta de qué números has asignado a la tarjeta. Esto lo puedes hacer con alguna lista de algún tipo o como prefieras. Para el generador de números aleatorios tienes muchas alternativas, que puedes encontrar por ejemplo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271598/java-generate-random-number-between-two-given-values)

Answer (score -1):

Para no complicarte la vida, lo más sencillo es utilizar la clase **`java.util.Random`**

Y una vez instanciado utilizas la variable » [**`Random r2 = new Random(4234);`**], sumado a esto lo metes en un bucle **`For`** y secuencias cuanta cantidad quieres de aleatorios.

Comment: Si le pasas como semilla un número literal, siempre se van a obtener los mismos números en los cartones. Lo lógico sería no pasarle valor a la semilla, y después utilizar el método `nextInt` para obtener los números aleatorios.